# Deny anonymous access to word doc in the website

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have hosted a asp.net (framework 4.0) website in a webserver. I'm using forms authentication in that. I have a folder in the webserver called 'ProfileData'.

```
<location path="ProfileData">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

So its denied anonymous access. and while i'm trying to access like,

www.mywebsite.com/ProfileData, then its redirecting to login page. But my issue is, when i'm trying

www.mywebsite.com/ProfileData/sample.docx, the word file is automatically downloading to the machine even if its a anonymous user.

How can i overcome this... please help me..

Thanks in advance...

Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you experineced the xml only works for html/aspx files. You have to implement a httphandler, sample can be found here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39158/Protect-Files-and-Folders-Using-HttpHandlers-in-AS